# Received negative reputation with no downvotes

Tags: support, reputation

I am not sure if this is the correct place for this, but...

I answered a question on Stack Overflow, and got one vote up and no votes down, however, I have *-15* points from that post. Why is that?

Here is a screenshot:

[image: -15 points]

Here is the post:

*[Get fractional portion of currency value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019708/get-fractional-portion-of-currency-value/46019737#46019737)*

Comment: you get 15 rep from an answer getting accepted. your answer isn't accepted, so it stands to reason that it was at one point in time accepted, and at this point in time it no longer is.

Comment: The OP unaccepted your answer. You can see it in your profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1778465/get-off-my-lawn?tab=reputation.

Comment: Ahh okay, I did not know that existed for some reason, thanks!

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn That information is literally stated for you *immediately* outside of the block that you showed in your screenshot.

Comment: @Servy there is no information for me, just `-15 [title]`

Comment: it have too many answers already

Comment: Why was this so heavily down voted? It's a good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when your answer was accepted and then later on unaccepted.